# Mobile Optimization - Conditionally load HTML depending on screen size

Tags: css, mobile, optimization, responsive-design, media-queries

I am redesigning my site for mobile first. I have read a few stackoverflow questions relating to this but none seemed to be a complete answer. I searched the web and came across http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/04/03/build-fast-loading-mobile-website/

In the **CODE FOR MOBILE-FIRST** section, it says the best way to conditionally load **images** for different screen sizes. What I'm looking for is that, but for html elements.

```
<div class="social_buttons">
   <ul>
      <li>google</li>
      <li>twitter</li>
      <li>facebook</li>
      <li>pinterest</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I **do not want** this section of html to be loaded when loaded from a mobile device, however I DO want it when called from desktop computer.

Using the solution from smashingmagazine (conditionally loaded using css) is it possible doing it this way or does it just apply to images?

Thanks for any help =)

Comment: Try bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 1):

one way is to redirect and load different html based on the device.

check this [Link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/redirect-mobile-devices/).

or use jquery plugin [Link](http://stephanfowler.github.io/responsive-content/).

I suggest using media queries to display respective content but using this method you load the whole HTML but display based on the device.

information about media queries -[LINK](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

like this

```
<div class="social_buttons">
   <ul>
      <li>google</li>
      <li>twitter</li>
      <li>facebook</li>
      <li>pinterest</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
@media (min-device-width: 640px) {
.social_buttons{
display:none;
  } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with javascript. Just do what you want in case of mobile or desktop.

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // mobile
} else {
 // desktop
}
```